# Correct way to cache images in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I am using the [ImageResizing](http://imageresizing.net) library, to resize and deliver my image in my C# Mvc application.

One thing that isn't happening though is my image aren't getting cached.

I am struggling to understand what would be required to appropriately add caching for each image.

I just need to know if I am on the write track? Will this cache my images correctly?

I think what I need to do, is set the FinalContentType, and FinalContentType in my ImageResizer_OnPostAuthorizeRequestStart (I dont know where to get these values)

And then, I am hoping that in the Application_PreSendRequestHeaders I can use the code below to set the cache headers correctly.

I have used a modified version of the method described [here](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls).

Here is my code:

```
 private static void ImageResizer_OnPostAuthorizeRequestStart(IHttpModule sender2, HttpContext context)
        {
            string path = Config.Current.Pipeline.PreRewritePath;
            if (!path.StartsWith(PathUtils.ResolveAppRelative("~/s3"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return;
        Config.Current.Pipeline.SkipFileTypeCheck = true;
        Config.Current.Pipeline.ModifiedQueryString["cache"] = ServerCacheMode.Always.ToString();
    }

    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = source as HttpApplication;

        HttpContext context = (app != null) ? app.Context : null;

        if (context != null && context.Items != null && context.Items["FinalContentType"] != null && context.Items["LastModifiedDate"] != null)
        {
            //Clear previous output 
            //context.Response.Clear(); 
            context.Response.ContentType = context.Items["FinalContentType"].ToString();

            //FinalContentType is set to image/jpeg or whatever the image mime-type is earlier in code. 
            //Add caching headers 
            int mins = 1; //Or Configuration.AppSettings['whatever'] 

            if (mins > 0)
            {
                context.Response.Expires = 1;
            }

            var lastModified = (DateTime?)context.Items["LastModifiedDate"]; //Set earlier in code. 

            if (lastModified != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                Response.Cache.SetLastModified(lastModified.Value);
            }

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(context.Request.IsAuthenticated ? HttpCacheability.Private : HttpCacheability.Public);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the `OutputCacheAttribute` not do what you want? Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: these images are resised at runtime by the library so the caching attribute wont work, also its the images specifically that i am trying to cache.

Comment: Why won't it work? MSDN says that it will cache the output of an action method in memory. Essentially, I understand that to mean whatever is written to the response is saved in memory.. that being, your binary image data.

Comment: So the images aren't necessarily coming via an action method, they are picked up through an httpmodule an served directly from a cloud storage with some processing. So the caching needs to happen on a per request level.

Comment: @Simon In practice, ASP.NET output caching doesn't work well for images -- when you can get it to work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DiskCache and ClientCache plugins to handle disk caching and cache headers respectively.

ASP.NET output caching is useless here.

Comment: why is output cache useless here? can u elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's useless, either.  A quick scan of  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19835/Creating-a-Custom-Output-Cache-Provider-in-ASPNET-4.htm looks promising (though again, not using ImageResizing).  The nice thing I recall about ImageResizing's DiskCache plugin is that, IIRC, there are a lot of tricks used to limit the amount of .NET code executed and IIS "handles serving the file directly". http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache

Comment: trying clientcache i think this is the way to go, but not quite there, other suggestions welcome while i try

Comment: ASP.NET output cache only functions in limited circumstances - when certain 'preconditions' are met - such as byte count (images are too large), response type, etc. Kernel-mode caching is only available for large responses when server from disk by IIS.

Comment: @JayC - That implementation in that article is not thread safe, cannot support invalidation or updates properly, and cannot leverage IIS or kernel-mode caching support.